# Android- Generate PDF file using android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf from an xml layout.I'm using android 
SDK API only. The pdf is generated but it is always empty. I'm using `android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument`. I tried finding solutions but could not solve this issue. Below is the code I'm using. Please help.

```
private void generateInvoice() {
        document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(597, 820, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.invoice_layout, null).draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PDF);
        } else {
            try {
                saveDocument();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void saveDocument() throws IOException {
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/YoScholarData");
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            if (direct.mkdir()) // if directory is created
                Log.d(TAG, "YoScholarData Folder Created.");
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'-HH-mm-ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String fileName = timeStamp + "_Invoice.pdf";
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/YoScholarData" + File.separator + fileName);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                document.writeTo(fo);
                document.close();
                fo.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "File Created in YoScholarData Folder.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invoice created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);

    }
```

`

Please help.

Comment: added write/read permissions?

Comment: @quick learner The pdf gets generated but its empty.

Comment: Where are you put pdf contents?

Comment: @BrianHoang at `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.invoice_layout, null).draw(page.getCanvas());`